# Python Coinbase API Authentication

Tags: python

**How do I create a sha256 HMAC using the secret key on the prehash string timestamp + method + requestPath + body (where + represents string concatenation)?**

I'm using **Python**

So far my code looks like this...

```
import hashlib
import time
import coinbase
import urllib3
import requests
import hmac
import base 64


apikey=‘ <apikey>‘
apisecret=‘ <apisecret>‘
method=“GET”
requestpath=“/v2/exchange-rates?currency=USD”
body=“ “
timestamp=int(time.time())
msg=timestamp + method + request path + body




dig = hmac.new(b’apisecret’, msg, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
base64.b64encode(dig).decode()
```

Thanks in advance,

Victor

Comment: Dont reinvent the wheel. https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-python

Comment: So creating the sha256 HMAC is not need for authentication? I'm trying to follow the API key authentication described here: https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication